# Fedora 24: increase disk space on /dev/mapper/fedora-var

Tags: linux, fedora

Here is my disk space usage:

```
Filesystem               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs                 1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs                    1.9G  296K  1.9G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                    1.9G  1.6M  1.9G   1% /run
tmpfs                    1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/fedora-root   46G  6.0G   38G  14% /
tmpfs                    1.9G   76K  1.9G   1% /tmp
/dev/mapper/fedora-var   9.1G  8.2G  444M  95% /var
/dev/mapper/fedora-home  138G   16G  115G  12% /home
tmpfs                    387M   12K  387M   1% /run/user/42
tmpfs                    387M   16K  387M   1% /run/user/1000
```

I got a 95% usage on /dev/mapper/fedora-var. I don't have much stuff to be cleaned and I am not sure whether cleaning the stuff would help in this issue. I would like to expand the disk space on /var, how could I do that? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved. My problem description is not accurate though, as some cache took the most of the space on /var. A combination of the following two links solved the issue:

1. Check disk usage on /var as described in http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=301185

   For my case I got 6.5G on /var/cache/PackageKit/metadata/updates/packages
2. Delete the cached data in this directory as described in [Fedora 23 -- Can I safely delete files in /var/cache/PackageKit/metadata/updates/packages?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/265755/fedora-23-can-i-safely-delete-files-in-var-cache-packagekit-metadata-updates)