# How to find and delete OS junk files on /var

Tags: files, fedora, rm, var

I tried to update my "Fedora" by using Terminal. It worked great at first but after a while it said that "there is not enough space in var/". I added some more space by using Gparted and now everything is OK. My question is, **How can I clean all useless downloaded files or junk files in var/?**
**Thank you for your help.**

**The tail of error was this**
" ***installing package fedora-chromium-config-1.1-3.fc31.noarch needs 81MB on the /var filesystem***

## *Error Summary*

**Disk Requirements: At least 81MB more space needed on the /var filesystem."

**These are in var/**

`account  crash  ftp       lib    log         nis       run    www
adm      db     games     local  lost+found  opt       spool  yp
cache    empty  kerberos  lock   mail        preserve  tmp`

**These are in cache/**

`abrt-di   cups  foomatic  gdm    ibus        ldconfig  libX11  PackageKit  realmd
app-info  dnf   fwupd     httpd  krb5rcache  libvirt   man     private`

Comment: Have a look in `/var/tmp` and `/var/spool` ?

Comment: @steve Dear Steve. Thank you for your reply. I used DU command to know how much space they were using and I got that tmp/ was using just 198 Mb and it was 52 Kb for spool/. Also, It was 412 Mb for cache/. All access denied files are missed in total! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just used `du -h | sort` command to know which directory get more space and I found that `/cache/PackageKit/31` is in charge. Using StackExchange, I find that I can remove all files in this directory with `sudo pkcon refresh force -c -1` but I've not dare to do this! Besides I have enough space on my hard-driver. Thank you for your helps.
[What I found](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/265755/fedora-23-can-i-safely-delete-files-in-var-cache-packagekit-metadata-updates)